# Update build definition in team foundation 2015 API

Tags: api, powershell, tfs, build, asp.net-core

I am busy with configuring our new TFS 2015 server (on premises) and trying to get the new vnext builds to work properly.
What I now have are some extra powershell scripts that increase the version number of my assemblies. 
It also changes the buildnumber in TFS by calling the API method (see [tfs rest api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview)). My json body only sends the new build number (eg. {"buildNumber": "1.0.1.1234"}) and this works fine.

Now I have added some major, minor and patch version variables in the build definition for the version. Once the build is done this should be updated and so I thought to do the same kind of thing and just send an update API call to the corresponding builddefinition endpoint. The documentation says the revision number is mandatory so I have added that. For the rest I only added the changed variables. 
The api call works, but the nasty thing is that it will update the whole definition and clear out all the other settings which I did not provide in the json body. I also tried first getting the defintion through the API, changing the json values for the variables and send that back but that didnt work correct also.

So does anybody know a good solution for this?

As a workaround what I did for now is adding a dummy build definition (eg. "_ProjectVersion") totally empty except for the variables and my build task now uses that build definition to get the latest version numbers and update them. So the api call still empties that whole build definition but since it only contains my variables I dont mind.

Comment: For your question:"but the nasty thing is that it will update the whole definition and clear out all the other settings which I did not provide in the json body", what are the unexpected changes you get? And any details on your json file with which we can use to try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I have used a json body like '{ id: 2, revision:15, variables: { MajorVersion: {value:1}, Minorversion: { value: '1'} ... }'
This wil only save these values in the build definition and removes all my previous settings (like all the build steps). 
The other way I tried was by first doing a GET on the build definition. Change the json response with my values and PUT that back again. Then I got exception messages like that the trigger array must have at least one value.

Comment: @chrisism I'm also having the same issues as you.  You'd expect if you gave the api back the exact thing that it gives you it would work, but apparently not.  I'm also trying to get this working so I will update you if I manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing this in powershell since all scripting should be automated and done in powershell.
The problem I have is that the API call to get the json of an existing BuildDefinition returns invalid json when managed in powershell.
For example the `"@{multipliers=[];` will fail with 'must have at least one value' even though a 'json validator' may report as Valid. The correct json is `{"multipliers": "[]",`

Comment: Yes, that is something I had issues with too. It doesnt look as correct JSON. 
I have to say that abandoning the trying to do it the right way and going with the empty _AppVersion build template works out perfect for me still. Since I have a nightly build and a release build that both need those version numbers using just one template is good enough. I dont care that its totally demolished every time since I only need to access those variables.
Still it would be nice if MS added some speciale variables support in build API.